# How does the scope of 'this' change in Function.prototype.call()

Tags: javascript

I have this example code below. I may be way off base, but I always understood `this` in javascript to mean the owner of the function/object that is the calling object.

```
function hello() {
  var hello = [this.name, this.sayHello].join('');
  console.log(hello);
}

var obj = {
  name: 'Chris', 
  sayHello: ', how are you today?'
};

hello.call(obj);
```

My next thought was what is happening is obj is now receiving the hello() function to its prototype. So I then ran this right after the `.call` function.

`obj.hello();`

To my suprise I received a type error: hello is not a function. Can anyone shed some light as to what is happening on the backend of this `.call()` javascript function?

**Edit**
Let me edit for clarity.
The question I am asking is "How does the scope of 'this' change? The function `hello()` should not have `this.name` in scope. unless the function hello was added to the prototype of `obj`. But it clearly works. So what trickery is happening on the Javascript function side of .call() for this to work.

Comment: `obj.hello()` would only work if you did `obj.hello = hello;` first.

Comment: The question is how does the scope of 'this' change? `hello.call(obj)` should still be the scope of the `hello` function but they are doing something to make obj contain the scope since I can call `this.name` from the function `hello` instead. It wasn't adding it to the prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) executes a function where `this` has been bound to the `thisArg`.

You can implement a similar function like this:

```js
Function.prototype.myCall = function(thisArg) {
  thisArg.myBoundCall = this;
  thisArg.myBoundCall();
  delete thisArg.myBoundCall;
}

function hello() {
  var hello = [this.name, this.sayHello].join('');
  console.log(hello);
}

var obj = {
  name: 'Chris',
  sayHello: ', how are you today?'
};

hello.myCall(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

By doing `hello.call(obj);`, it doesn't then create a new method on your obj object named hello, to use later.

Comment: It doesn't seem that way, I received an error that hello is not a function on object. I also looked through the prototype on obj, and didn't see that function.

Comment: Correct. If you want that behaviour, you might try [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which is fairly new.

Comment: I want to understand how the back end .call is working to change the 'this' scope to be on the `obj` instead of the function `hello`. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: It's built into the specification, and thus the browsers implement it in their JavaScript engine. There is no userland code for this, it just works :). To dig a little though, consider what `this` refers to when invoking the function with `hello()`. It isn't contained within a object, or is it? Everything defined in the global scope will become `window.*` in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the object specified in `hello.call`. You can, by other way, define `hello` as method of `this`.

```
function hello() {
    this.hello = function() {
        console.log([this.name, this.sayHello].join(''));
    }
}
```